# MicroPython to Arduino

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

Is there an Arduino equivalent to MicroPython's `put()` and `get()`?

I want to use an assembled Pico PIO routine with a Pico using the Arduino IDE (earlephilhower).
The MicroPython main program uses both a `put()` and a `get()` statement.
What is the Arduino equivalent?

**Added 02-13-2024**
For example: in MicroPython,
to input a value from main to a PIO State Machine, we use

```
myValue = 24<br>
sm1.**put**(myValue)<br>
```

where `sm1` is the name of the PIO State Machine.

The PIO State Machine inputs `myValue` with a `_pull( )_` instruction.

To output a value from a PIO State Machine to main,
the PIO instruction is `_push( )_`
and in main, we use `newValue = sm1.**get( )**`

What is the syntax for `put( )` and `get( )` if we wish to program the Pico using the Arduino IDE with a Pico RP2040 board?

Comment: `get()` and `put()` from what class or module?  Those names are far too generic for us to have any idea what you're referring to.

Comment: Micropython does not has the put() or get(), It is the class instance sm1 that has the implementation of  the put() and get() methods that give your the ability to call those methods. Arduino is in C++, and none of these make any sense in C++ without the context of what you are dealing with.